# Is there a matrix that converts the gradient of any function to gradient of other function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

The study of hamiltonian mechanics brought me to the following question.

Let $n$ be a natural number ($n>1$).

Let $A(\mathbf{x})$ be a $n\times n$ matrix consisting of functions $a_{ij}(\mathbf{x})$ ($a_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$):
$$
A(\mathbf{x})=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}(\mathbf{x})& \cdots& a_{1n}(\mathbf{x})\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}(\mathbf{x})&\cdots& a_{nn}(\mathbf{x})
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Let $A(\mathbf{x})$ be so, that for *any* $F(\mathbf{x})$ ($F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}(\mathbf{x})& \cdots& a_{1n}(\mathbf{x})\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}(\mathbf{x})&\cdots& a_{nn}(\mathbf{x})
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_n}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
g_1(\mathbf{x})\\
\vdots\\
g_n(\mathbf{x})
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_1}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_n}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $G(\mathbf{x})$ ($G:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R})$.

In other words, if we multiply *fixed* $A(\mathbf{x})$ by the gradient of *any* $F(\mathbf{x})$ we necessarily get the gradient of some $G(\mathbf{x})$.

Can we say anything about such $A(\mathbf{x})$? I would be glad if the only opportunity is that $A(\mathbf{x})=cE$, where $E$ is the identity matrix and $c$ is some real number. Is it correct? Is it possible to prove it?

All the functions are considered to be "good enough" ("smooth enough").

Comment: Your hope that $A(x) = cE$ is shattered, just consider $F(x) \equiv 0$.

Comment: @Wauzl I need a matrix $A(\mathbf{x})$ that converts the gradient of **every possible** $F(\mathbf{x})$ to the gradient of some $G(\mathbf{x})$. The fact that some $A(\mathbf{x})$ converts the gradient of $F(\mathbf{x})\equiv0$ to gradient does not mean that the same $A(\mathbf{x})$ will work that well for **all other possible** $F(\mathbf{x})$. Probably the word "any" made the whole statement ambiguous.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution (with the help of Mathoverflow users).

See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239275/is-there-a-matrix-that-converts-the-gradient-of-every-possible-function-to-gradi

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @sandwich Do you mean that the solution on Mathoverflow is wrong, or the message here is not informative? If latter, how can I give the link to the discussion on Mathoverflow? I wouldn't like to delete the question, because it may be useful for further users.